# Getting rows from the same week and month

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm being given a `datetime` String where I need to have two separate queries, one that gets all of the records in that week, and one that gets all the records in that month.

so for the example the week query:  today is `2021-08-25 06:00:00` how would I get the records in that column where the earliest would be

`2021-08-23 00:00:00` and the latest would be at the end of the week `2021-08-29 23:59:59`

Same for a day in the month

Is using greater + less than the correct way to approach this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about performance, you could just use:

```
where year(start_timestamp) = year(@date) and
      week(start_timestamp) = week(@date)
```

And similarly:

```
where year(start_timestamp) = year(@date) and
      month(start_timestamp) = month(@date)
```

Note that MySQL cannot use an index on this.  This also only uses `start_timestamp`.  Your question doesn't explain at all how two timestamps are supposed to fit into the criteria.  And the definition of week is whatever `week()` decides it is.

Comment: yeah I removed the timestamps because they were confusing the question. I need the rows that are in the same week as the provided String ```2021-08-25 06:00:00```. I don't know how to phrase it any better sorry. ```SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date is same week as 2021-08-25 06:00:00``` something like that. I don't know how I would do it with sql

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE . . . That is what the first of the queries does.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly because I'm getting zero rows returned ```SELECT * FROM appointments where year(date_start_column) = year(@'2021-08-03') and week(date_start_column) = week(@'2021-08-03')```. I have a row in the ```date_start_column``` with the date ```2021-08-02``` but it's not returning it

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE . . . `@date` is a place holder for the parameter that holds your date.

Comment: :D thanks for bearing with me. The query works perfectly